# How to parse two different JSON formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I need to parse 2 different types of JSONs as shown below:

JSON 1:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "sno": "1",
      "project_name": "Abs",
      "project_Status": "Live"
    },
    {
      "sno": "2",
      "project_name": "Cgi",
      "project_Status": "Live"
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON 2:

```
[
  {
    "sno": "1",
    "project_name": "Disc",
    "project_Status": "Live"
  },
  {
    "sno": "2",
    "project_name": "Rol",
    "project_Status": "Live"
  }
]
```

I was parsing the JSON 2 as follows:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "sample.json")))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject jsonPayload = JObject.Load(reader);
            jsonProfile = jsonPayload.ToString();
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonProfile);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to modify this to check if the JSON is in type 1 or type 2 and then parse it to assign each project to a different JObject?

Comment: What is type1 and type2? The only differences between your two examples (despite the fact that the `project_name`s are different), is that the first has a `{` in front. Is this what you mean by different types?

Comment: You already parse the object in the *first* line. Why parse it *again*? Besides, the *first* string will return an object (JObject) with a `projects` property while the second will return a JArray. The snippet works only because a JArray inherits from JObject. The only change needed is to use JToken instead of JObject

Comment: @HimBromBeere when I am parsing the JSON 2 with the code given, the entire JSON is getting assigned to a single JObject. Due to this, I am unable to separate the different projects

Answer (score 1):

Unless your JSON is large (thousands of lines), I would dispense with the reader altogether.  Instead, read the whole JSON file into a string using [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_) and parse it using [`JToken.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm).  From there it is easy to check whether you have an array (JSON 2) or an object containing an array (JSON 1) and then process accordingly:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "sample.json");
string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
JArray array = (token.Type == JTokenType.Array) ? (JArray)token : (JArray)token["projects"];
foreach (JObject project in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("number: " + (string)project["sno"]);
    Console.WriteLine("name: " + (string)project["project_name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("status: " + (string)project["project_Status"]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lA87Xo