# Unable to parse JSON with multiple JObjects

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am having a string in the following format. I want to assign each JSON within the projects to a separate JObject. When I am trying to parse it and assign accordingly, I am unable to achieve it. How can I parse it?

```
 {
      "projects": [
        {
          "sno": "1",
          "project_name": "Abs",
          "project_Status": "Live"
        },
        {
          "sno": "2",
          "project_name": "Cgi",
          "project_Status": "Live"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have tried the following code;

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "sample.json")))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject jsonPayload = JObject.Load(reader);
            jsonProfile = jsonPayload.ToString();
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonProfile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dbc Updated my question with the code I have tried

Comment: This question seems like a duplicate of [your question from 16 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53261323/10263) except with only one JSON format instead of two.  Did the answer to that one not help you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)  as a simpler solution to parse json.

```
var definition = new
{
    projects = new[]{
            new {
              sno="1",
              project_name= "Abs",
              project_Status= "Live"
            }
    }
};

string json1 = @" {
                  'projects': [
                    {
                                'sno': '1',
                      'project_name': 'Abs',
                      'project_Status': 'Live'
                    },
                    {
                            'sno': '2',
                      'project_name': 'Cgi',
                      'project_Status': 'Live'
                    }
                  ]
                }";
var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);
```

but if you do want to use `strong type`, you'd better to use `JsonProperty`

```
public class Project
{
    [JsonProperty("sno")]
    public string Sno { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("project_name")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("project_Status")]
    public string ProjectStatus { get; set; }
}

public class JsonModel
{
    [JsonProperty("Projects")]
    public List<Project> projects { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json_Data);
```